# Regex in unix for date

Tags: regex, linux, date

I want to search for all occurences of date in following format in a file using shell scripting in linux.

> Apr 24 2014

Comment: i have tried this.
[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{4}

Comment: @PrateekGupta `[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{4}` might work better. But you haven't told us in what way yours doesn't work.

Comment: i get this output.
Apr:not found
i think it is not searching after space and  as it encounters space after Apr it stops saying NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 0 — Plain old `sed`**

```
sed -n '/\(Jan\|Feb\|Mar\|Apr\|May\|Jun\|Jul\|Aug\|Sep\|Oct\|Nov\|Dec\) [0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{4\}/p'
```

Better to have every possible month exactly specified.

**Method 1 — Extended RE with `grep`**

```
grep -E '(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}'
```

The `-E` switch is necessary to make `grep` interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression, with a much less cumbersome syntax.

**Method 2 — Variation on a Theme**

```
awk '$0 ~ /(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}/ 1'
```

`awk` comes with extended RE out of the box!

**Method 3 — Let's employ Perl's mightiness.**

The task at hand could be most easily accomplished by means of the [Regex::Common::time](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm#Year-Month-Day_order) module.  You need to have it installed, of course.

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -MRegexp::Common::time -nle '/$RE{time}{mdy}/ && print'
```

Comment: cant use perl. trying method 0 and 1